# A convergent power series' tail goes to $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Let $\phi$ be defined as such:

\begin{equation}
\phi(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2}
\end{equation}

By Hadamard's theorem, the radius of convergence of $\phi$ equals $1$. In particular for $z \in \partial D(0, 1)$, the series remains absolutely convergent (it converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$) therefore $\phi$ is absolutely convergent over $\overline{D(0, 1)}$.

I now want to prove that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, one can find a $n_\varepsilon >0 $ such that, for all $ m \geq n_\varepsilon$,

\begin{equation}
\Big|\sum_{n \geq m}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2} \Big| < \varepsilon, \quad z \in D(0, 1).
\end{equation}

I'm only looking for tips on how to get started. Thank you.

Comment: The radius of convergence is infinite. This series is $e^z$. I don't get the reference to $\pi^2/6$.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake in the definition of $\phi$. I apologize.

Comment: Observe that $\lvert \sum_{n \geq m}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} \rvert = \lvert \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} - \sum_{n = 1}^{m-1} \frac{z^n}{n!} \rvert$.

Comment: I've revised the question.

Comment: Maybe the Cauchy condition for convergence of a series can be useful (not the Cauchy condensation test).

Comment: Simply note that $$\Big|\sum_{n \geqslant m}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2} \Big|\leqslant\sum_{n \geqslant m}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$ which goes to $0$ when $m\to\infty$.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!

Comment: I don't think the series converges to $\;\cfrac{\pi^2}6\;$ for $\;z\in\partial D(0,1)\;$ **except** $\;z=1\;$ ...In fact, it doesn't.

Comment: Yes it does. It converges absolutely because $|z| = 1$ for $z \in \partial D(0, 1)$.